# How to configure a variable from build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

know might be pretty simple, but i can't figure out which could be the best approach here.

Assuming i have an app which works for company A ( named "Apple") and which is perfect also for company B (named "Microsoft") , and i want them to have the same app, just with the company name written on the main page.

What I need here is to have 2 different builds in my build.gradle in which , having the company name written there , i can value on the OnCreate a parameter with the same value specified in the build.gradle.

Which is the best approach here?

EDIT:

I tried putting this line in the release buildtypes:

```
buildConfigField "String", "company", "\"APPLE\""
```

but i can't retrieve value using

```
BuildConfig.company
```

which doesn't exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create productFlavors in gradle file and define different source sets. You will get detailed help in the official page. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#workBuildVariants

If it is just a matter of one string, and above is a lot of work then look at
https://www.tanelikorri.com/tutorial/android/set-variables-in-build-gradle/
It's a nice article.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with the 2nd approach,             
buildConfigField "String", "company", "\"APPLE\""

but i can't retrieve value using 

BuildConfig.company

which doesn't exists

Comment: use resValue, not buildConfigField. buildConfigField is used to set build config variables